# java how to keep a int as a int by rounding after the calculation

Tags: java

i want to keep a int as a int but after multiplying it by x value im left with a double value, what can i do to round it to keep it as type int

```
 Math.round(acutalTime) = (acutalTime * 0.9);
```

this is what ive tried so far but it doesnt compile

taking the suggestion into account changed it to

```
acutalTime = Math.round(acutalTime * 0.9);
```

but i am getting a error about cannot convert possible loss from long to int

Comment: You cannot use a function on the left side of an assignment. You'd need to do actualTime = Math.round(actualTime * 0.9);

Answer (score 0):

```
acutalTime = (int) Math.round(acutalTime*0.9)
```